# Finding marginal probability distribution of $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 2\exp(-x)\exp(-y)$, how to set up limits of integration and domain of marginal PDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In this example from [notes](https://homepages.wmich.edu/~bazuinb/ECE5820/Notes5.pdf), pg. 19, we need to find the marginal probability distribution of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$

[image]

The marginal probability distribution were found to be

[image]

I have been thinking about this for a while but I am still not sure how to answer these questions:

**1. Why is the limit of the first integral (i.e. $\int\limits_0^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) dy$) from $0$ to $x$, instead of $0$ to $\infty$?**

Didn't we explicitly specify that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is defined as $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 2\exp(-x)\exp(-y)$$ over $0 \leq y \leq x < \infty$? Ignoring $x$ for a second, then we have $0 \leq y < \infty$. Then the limit of integration should be from $0$ to $\infty$. But why not?

**2. Why is the PDF $f_X(x)$ defined over $0 \leq x < \infty$ and not $y \leq x < \infty$.**

Didn't we explicitly specify that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is defined as $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 2\exp(-x)\exp(-y)$$ over $0 \leq y \leq x < \infty$. See, $x$ has a lower bound of $y$, not zero. Hence the marginal PDF $f_X(x)$ should be defined on $y \leq x < \infty$, and not $0 \leq x < \infty$

What would be a satisfactory resolution to both of these questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, in order to get the marginal PDF for $X$ we integrate the joint PDF over $y$ $$ f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\; dy.$$

In order to determine the limits to use when you plug in the functional form for $f_{X,Y},$ you need to consider the support of the function. Remember that $x$ is a free variable here so we treat it as a fixed number. Since the joint PDF has support in the region $0 < y < x <\infty$ when we integrate over $y,$ the support stops at $x$ so we have limits $\int_0^x.$ In other words, we cannot "ignore $x$ for a second"... $x$ is a fixed number and must be taken into account.

For the second question, there is not even a notion of $y$ in $f_X(x)$... $y$ has already been integrated out. In other words, it's not a free variable here. So considering $f_X$ to have support $y<x<\infty$ wouldn't even make sense... we'd need to ask "what is $y$?" You have already averaged over *all* values of $y$, there is no single value that it makes sense to specify.

To see that the correct lower limit for the support of $f_X$ is zero, we only need observe that this is the smallest value of $x$ where $f_{X,Y}$ has support. In general it helps to sketch the support in the $x-y$ plane. Here it is the region of the first quadrant between the positive $x$ axis and the line $y=x.$